# How to make my calculator compute time correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, time, ios4

I'm working with iOS 4, Objective C. 
This is the code I have now.

```
float minutes = ([time.text floatValue]);
float miles = minutes/([distance.text floatValue]);

label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", miles];
```

I want to just multiply the decimal after this is completed. How can i do this?

Comment: Long story short, I dont want decimals to go over 59.

Comment: Without seeing your code, how can we possibly give you suggestions about what to fix?

Comment: you need to post some example code

Comment: how about multiplying your decimal by 1/6 ?

Comment: As an aside your variable names are terrible `x`, `c`, `textfield1`, `textfield2` and `label`. It may seem clear to you what they are now but when you look at it in 3 months' time you'll have forgotten. Also, if you had used more descriptive names your example code might give us an idea of what you are trying to do, which helps us to help you. **Use descriptive variable names** you really will find that it helps your write and read code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulus operator: Seconds % 60

Comment: First I would divide the seconds by 60 and round that number down and add it to your minutes then I would take the original seconds %60 to get the correct answer