# How to multiply only decimal

Tags: xcode, time, calculator

I'm using iOS, and I want to be able to multiply the decimal after one answer is solved. This is what I have so far:

```
float minutes = ([time.text floatValue]);
float distance = minutes/([miles.text floatValue]);

label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", distance];
```

Is it possible to just multiply the remainder by 60 after this is done?
For example, if I put in 50 divided by 3, it gives me 16.66 as an answer. I want to multiply this .66.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my calculator compute time correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302310/how-to-make-my-calculator-compute-time-correctly)

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to do? What is "the decimal?"

Comment: What does "I want to multiply this .66." mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess at what you're asking since I cannot discern it from your question. It looks to me like you are trying to calculate a pace from a time and distance and display it in units of time/distance. If this is what you're trying to do, then your code should look something like this:

```
float mins = [time.text floatValue];
float dist = [miles.text floatValue];
float pace = mins/dist;
```

To display the pace correctly in `min:sec` format, you can do this:

```
int minutes = (int)pace; // casting truncates the decimal part
int seconds = (int)((pace - minutes) * 60);
```

Now you can display the pace with

```
NSLog(@"%d:%d",minutes,seconds);
```

If that's not what you're doing, then please clarify your question.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @parker: Great. If this works for you, then please click that little check mark to indicate that it worked. Otherwise, let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've been looking for this for far to long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking for, but I think you want to get the fractional portion of your number.

To retrieve the fractional portion of the result, use `floor`:

```
float fraction = result - floor(result);
```

Results:

```
      result   = 50.0 / 3

      fraction = 16.666666 - 16.000000

      fraction = 0.666666
```

Subtracting the `floor` of a number from the number gives the fraction. (The `floor` function strips the fraction (rounding down), allowing you to retrieve it by subtraction.)